# Signing url's in Windows Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, cdn, akamai, azure-media-services

I am trying to find an equivalent feature in Windows Azure Media Services to the following S3 feature: http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-generate-url-for-amazon-s3-file.html#signedurl

I have heard that signing urls like this can be achieved through S3 as well CDN's (like Akamai).

2 questions.

1) Does anybody have recommendations on how to implement signed URL's in WAMS?

2) Does anybody know to what extend Azure will hook in with other CDN's like Akamai?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Equivalent for this feature in Windows Azure is called [Shared Access Signature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/). Media Services does support creating of [SAS Origin Locators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974308.aspx).

You can read the official documentation on [how to create SAS Locator with .NET SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129575.aspx#create_sas_locator).

Or you can check [my project on GitHub](https://github.com/astaykov/WaMediaWeb) and the [Locators implementation in particular](https://github.com/astaykov/WaMediaWeb/blob/master/WaMedia.Common/Implementations/LocatorService.cs)

A Code sample for generating SAS Locator for particular asset follows:

```
public string GetSasLocator(IAsset asset)
{
    // Create an 1-day readonly access policy. 
    IAccessPolicy streamingPolicy = this.MediaService.MediaContext.AccessPolicies.Create("Full Access Policy",
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
        AccessPermissions.List | AccessPermissions.Read | AccessPermissions.Read);

    // Create the origin locator. Set the start time as 5 minutes 
    // before the present so that the locator can be accessed immediately 
    // if there is clock skew between the client and server.
    ILocator sasLocator =
        (from l in this.MediaService.MediaContext.Locators
         where l.Type == LocatorType.Sas && l.AssetId.Equals(asset.Id)
         select l).FirstOrDefault();

    if (sasLocator != null && sasLocator.ExpirationDateTime < DateTime.UtcNow)
    {
        sasLocator.Delete();
        sasLocator = null;
    }

    if (sasLocator == null)
    {
        sasLocator = this.MediaService.MediaContext
            .Locators.CreateSasLocator(asset,
         streamingPolicy,
         DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5));
    }
    // Create a full URL to the manifest file. Use this for playback
    // in streaming media clients. 
    string sasUrl = sasLocator.Path;

    // Display the full URL to the streaming manifest file.
    Console.WriteLine("URL to for blob upload: ");
    Console.WriteLine(sasUrl);

    return sasUrl;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks I will take a look in a little bit.  My understanding though was that SAS locators are designed for content that IS NOT adaptive bit rate.  HLS and Smooth Streaming for example require Origin Locators (should have put that in my original post).  Can you still use this approach with HLS or Smooth Streaming?

Comment: Another note, it looks to me like your code (on github and here) covers the Time To Live (expiration) portion, but it does not quite cover the security potion.  The signed URL feature listed above ensures that consumers of any URL must make a cert / signature hand shake before a URL will load.  This portion needs to be supported as well.